# Start Process when Record Shared Option

Tags: crm

Is it possible to add a Record Shared trigger for Processes like below? If not what would suggest as an alternative method of achieving this or the next best thing?

Thanks,

Killian

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can trigger a workflow when a record is shared but you can trigger a plugin on "GrantAccess" to carry out your desired logic.

http://howto-mscrm.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-series-11-how-to-trigger-plugin.html